# How to use multiple version of tricore-gcc.exe compilers with waf

Tags: python, build, waf

I want to use different `tricore-gcc.exe` for different project in windows OS

the two `tricore-gcc.exe` are in the following paths and they are not in PATH:

- `C:\HighTec\toolchains\tricore\v4.6.3.0\bin\tricore-gcc.exe`
- `C:\HighTec\toolchains\tricore\v4.9.2.0\bin\tricore-gcc.exe`

My question is how to config it in waf?

Is `compiler_c` only search `msvc`, `gcc` and `clang` ?

Thanks for any suggestion!

(I have searched in Stackoverflow, such as [Specify different compilers in waf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53833374/specify-different-compilers-in-waf) but I found no answer about how to set an absolute path in Windows )

my `wscript`:

```py
def options(opt):
    print("start opt ------------------")
    opt.load('compiler_c')

def configure(conf):
    # here we are in default variant/env
    # we load the default compiler, probably gcc
    conf.load('compiler_c')

    # config for tricore 4.6.3 variant
    print("start ------------------")
    conf.setenv('t463')
    conf.env.CC = ['C:\HighTec\toolchains\tricore\v4.6.3.0\bin\tricore-gcc.exe']

    conf.load('compiler_c')

    # config for tricore 4.9.2 variant
    print("start ------------------")
    conf.setenv('t492')
    conf.env.CC = ['C:\HighTec\toolchains\tricore\v4.9.2.0\bin\tricore-gcc.exe']

    conf.load('compiler_c')

    # back to default config
    conf.setenv('')

def build(bld):

    bld.program(source = 'main.c', target = 'myexe')

# this create variants commands and build directories

from waflib.Build import (
    BuildContext,
    CleanContext,
    InstallContext,
    UninstallContext,
)

for variant in ['t463', 't492']:
    for context in [BuildContext, CleanContext, InstallContext, UninstallContext]:

        name = context.__name__.replace('Context','').lower()

        class tmp(context):
            cmd = name + '_' + variant
            variant = variant
```

I tested it and get the result:

```
D:\CX\15_waf\test1>python waf configure

start opt ------------------
Setting top to                           : D:\CX\15_waf\test1
Setting out to                           : D:\CX\15_waf\test1\build
Checking for 'msvc' (C compiler)         : not found
Checking for 'gcc' (C compiler)          : not found
Checking for 'clang' (C compiler)        : not found
could not configure a C compiler!
(complete log in D:\CX\15_waf\test1\build\config.log)
```

The `config.log`:

```
# project  configured on Tue Dec 29 14:42:29 2020 by
# waf 2.0.21 (abi 20, python 30803f0 on win32)
# using waf configure
#

----------------------------------------
Setting top to D:\CX\15_waf\test1
----------------------------------------
Setting out to D:\CX\15_waf\test1\build
----------------------------------------
Checking for 'msvc' (C compiler)
['C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\Installer\\vswhere.exe', '-products', '*', '-legacy', '-format', 'json']
from D:\CX\15_waf\test1: msvc: Impossible to find a valid architecture for building [] - [] 
not found
----------------------------------------
Checking for 'gcc' (C compiler)
find program=['gcc', 'cc'] paths=['C:\\Testwell\\CTC', 'C:\\Java\\j2sdk1.4.2_11\\bin', 'C:\\Windows\\system32', 'C:\\Windows', 'C:\\Windows\\System32\\Wbem', 'C:\\Windows\\System32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\', 'C:\\Program Files\\Intel\\WiFi\\bin\\', 'C:\\Program Files\\Common Files\\Intel\\WirelessCommon\\', 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Common Files\\ETAS\\3rdParty1.0', 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Toolbase Client', 'C:\\Users\\xia.chen\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Microsoft VS Code\\bin', 'C:\\Users\\xia.chen\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Git\\cmd', 'C:\\HighTec\\toolchains\\tricore\\v4.9.2.0\\bin', 'D:\\tools\\Python38', 'D:\\tools\\Python38\\Scripts', 'C:\\HighTec\\toolchains\\tricore\\v4.9.2.0\\bin'] var='CC' -> None
from D:\CX\15_waf\test1: Could not find the program ['gcc', 'cc']
not found
----------------------------------------
Checking for 'clang' (C compiler)
find program=['clang'] paths=['C:\\Testwell\\CTC', 'C:\\Java\\j2sdk1.4.2_11\\bin', 'C:\\Windows\\system32', 'C:\\Windows', 'C:\\Windows\\System32\\Wbem', 'C:\\Windows\\System32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\', 'C:\\Program Files\\Intel\\WiFi\\bin\\', 'C:\\Program Files\\Common Files\\Intel\\WirelessCommon\\', 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Common Files\\ETAS\\3rdParty1.0', 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Toolbase Client', 'C:\\Users\\xia.chen\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Microsoft VS Code\\bin', 'C:\\Users\\xia.chen\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Git\\cmd', 'C:\\HighTec\\toolchains\\tricore\\v4.9.2.0\\bin', 'D:\\tools\\Python38', 'D:\\tools\\Python38\\Scripts', 'C:\\HighTec\\toolchains\\tricore\\v4.9.2.0\\bin'] var='CC' -> None
from D:\CX\15_waf\test1: Could not find the program ['clang']
not found
from D:\CX\15_waf\test1: could not configure a C compiler!
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes waf detect only supported compilers defined in compiler_c.

If your compiler is "compatible" as clang is compatible to gcc (ie its command line work the same) then you just have to define `CC`:

```py
from waflib import Logs

# this is to check only for gcc-like compiler, on win32, compiler_c begins with msvc
from waflib.Tools.compiler_c import c_compiler
c_compiler['win32'] = ['gcc']

def options(opt):
    opt.load('compiler_c')

def configure(conf):

    conf.setenv('t463')
    conf.env.CC = ['c:/toolchains/tricore/v4.6.3.0/bin/tricore-gcc.exe']
    conf.load('compiler_c')

    conf.setenv('t492')
    conf.env.CC = ['c:/toolchains/tricore/v4.9.2.0/bin/tricore-gcc.exe']
    conf.load('compiler_c')

def build(bld):

    Logs.info("Using compiler {}".format(bld.env.CC))
    bld.program(source = 'main.c', target = 'myexe')
```

Note: I tested on Linux, no win32 box available :)

To detect a new "incompatible" compiler, you have to do something like:

```py
from waflib.Tools.compiler_c import c_compiler
c_compiler['win32'] = ['tricore', 'msvc', 'gcc']

def options(opt):
    opt.load('compiler_c')
def configure(cnf):
    cnf.load('compiler_c')
def build(bld):
    bld.program(source='main.c', target='myexe')
```

And define a `tricore` tool to detect the compiler:

```py
# from waflib/Tools/clang.py

from waflib.Tools import ccroot, ar, gcc
from waflib.Configure import conf

@conf
def find_tricore(conf):
    cc = conf.find_program('tricore', var='CC')
    conf.get_cc_version(cc)
    conf.env.CC_NAME = 'tricore'

def configure(conf):
    conf.find_tricore()
    conf.find_ar()
    conf.gcc_common_flags()
    conf.gcc_modifier_platform()
    conf.cc_load_tools()
    conf.cc_add_flags()
    conf.link_add_flags()
```

You can have a look at `gcc.py`, `clang.py`, `suncc.py` or `icc.py` for a compiler like `gcc`. Look at `msvc.py` for a compiler really different from `gcc`.